# Can I start the polling service by call ? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polling

i have written a polling service in AngularJS and want to start the service if my post request is done.But if I call the gui, the poll service is active.

i have try to implement a start function, end function and call the start() function if the post request is done.. but it doesnt work :/

My poll service :

```
.factory('NotificationPollService',
['$http', '$q', '$interval',
function ($http, $q, $interval) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var notification = {};

    notification.poller = $interval(function(id) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/id', {cache: false})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             return data;
        }, 10000);
    });

    notification.endPolling = function() {$interval.cancel(this.interval);};
```

}])

and the controller which i post the request

```
.controller('HomeController',
['$scope', '$rootScope', 'SendJmeterFile', 'NotificationPollService',
function ($scope, $rootScope, SendJmeterFile , NotificationPollService) {

    $scope.upload = function() {

        var customArtifacts = "";
        var testDataBase = "";

        if($scope.jmeterFile.customArtifact == undefined){
            customArtifacts = null;
        } else {customArtifacts = $scope.jmeterFile.customArtifact.base64}

        if($scope.jmeterFile.testDataBase == undefined){
            testDataBase = null;
        } else {testDataBase = $scope.jmeterFile.testDataBase.base64}

        SendJmeterFile.upload($scope.jmeterFile.jmeter.base64, customArtifacts, $scope.jmeterFile.customProperties, $scope.jmeterFile.instanceConfiguration, $scope.jmeterFile.instances, $scope.jmeterFile.providerID, testDataBase)
            .then(function(data) {
                alert("Daten erfolgreich verschickt!");
                console.log(data);  
                NotificationPollService.poller(data.id)
                //.then(function(data) {
                    /*if(data.status == "SETUP")

                    if(data.status == "TEST")

                    if(data.status == "DONE")

                    if(data.status == "ERROR")
                }), function(data) {
                    })*/
            }, function(data) {
                alert("Fehler!");
                console.log(data);
            });     
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that `$interval()` is called immediately upon injection into your controller. Your hunch to implement a 'Start' method or something similar was a good one - but you can probably simplify it even more by letting the factory return a function. Then you can just instantiate that function in your controller as many times as you need a Poller.

However, there are more problems. A promise can only be resolved once, and since you execute a HTTP request multiple times, my guess is that you want to be 'notified' of state changes until the state is marked as 'Done'. You're currently putting the responsibility for checking the state with the controller. If all you want is to be notified of "error" and "success" steps however, it is probably much better to let the `Poller` service be responsible for interpreting the state information that comes back from your service, and simply depend on standard promise behaviour in your controller. I opted to show an example of the latter case:

UPDATE: sample plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/e7vqU82fqYGQuCwufPZN?p=preview

```
angular.module('MYMODULENAMEHERE')
.factory('NotificationPoller',
    ['$http', '$q', '$interval',
    function ($http, $q, $interval) {

        return poller;

        function poller(id) {
            var _this = this;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var interval = $interval(function() {
                $http
                    // I assumed you actually want to use the value of 'id' in your
                    // url here, rather than just the word 'id'.
                    .get('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/' + id, {cache: false})
                    .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // I commented out the following statement. It is meaningless because
                        // you can't do anything with the return value since it's an anonymous
                        // function you're returning it from. Instead, you probably meant to 
                        // use the promise to return the data.

                        // return data;

                        if(data.status == "SETUP") {
                            deferred.notify(data);
                        }
                        else if(data.status == "TEST") {
                            deferred.notify(data);
                        }
                        else if(data.status == "DONE") {
                            _this.endPolling(); // Automatically stop polling when status is done
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        }
                        else { // data.status == "ERROR" (or anything else that's not expected)
                            _this.endPolling(); // Automatically stop polling on error
                            deferred.reject(data);
                        }                       
                    }, function(data) {
                        _this.endPolling();
                        deferred.reject(data);
                    });
            }, 10000);

            this.endPolling = function() {
                $interval.cancel(interval);
            };

            // Make the promise available to calling code
            this.promise = deferred.promise;
        };
}])
```

Now your controller can much more easily use your polling service. Here's an example of a stripped-down controller using your polling service, for clarity:

```
angular.module('MYMODULENAMEHERE')
.controller('HomeController', [
    'NotificationPoller',
    function(NotificationPoller) {

        var some_id = 207810;

        var poller = new NotificationPoller(some_id);
        poller.promise.then(onSuccess, onError, onNotify);

        function onSuccess(data) {
            // data.status == "DONE"
        };

        function onError(data) {
            // data.status == "ERROR"
        };

        function onNotify(data) {
            // data.status == "TEST" || data.status == "SETUP"
        };

    }]);
```

As you see, the factory has received a little more responsibility this way, but your controller doesn't need to be aware of the details of all the statuses that the backend can send anymore. It just uses standard promises.

Comment: thanks for this helpful answer ! i have try it and get the error, that NotificationPollService is not a constructor, can i initialize the NotificationPollService in the SendJMeterFile.upload.then .. success function ?

Comment: this is a good case scenario of my task : send the file to the server, the server execute it and set the status depends on the step the server in (running, done, error, test) and in that time i want to poll the service with the id of the response of the server. so i think i call the poll service on the success case after the post request or am I wrong ?

Comment: Yep, that's the assumption I made based on your initial code. I'm not sure why you're receiving that error, though it could have something to do with the fact that you might have copied my code directly? It won't work because in the sample scripts I haven't defined an angular module. I've created a Plnkr for you which works (minus the actual backend, of course), so perhaps you can have a look to see if this is more useful to you: http://plnkr.co/edit/e7vqU82fqYGQuCwufPZN?p=preview

Comment: thank you so much, i have it solve now, the problem was, that i inject the notificationservice to the success fall :/, your solution is very elegant and simple, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You try to call `NotificationPollService.poller(data.id)` which is [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#usage), actually, because previously in `NotificationPollService` you assigned `notification.poller` like so

```
notification.poller = $interval(function(id) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/id', {cache: false})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         return data;
    }, 10000);
});
```

Now your `notification.poller` is a return value of `$interval` function.
To make it work you should wrap the function so you could actually pass an id to it.

Comment: if i delete the NotificationPollService.poller(data.id), the interval function is still active if i upload a file :/ what do you mean with wrap the function ? i

Comment: I assumed alert('Daten erfolgreich verschickt!') actually alerted a string. Is this right?

Comment: yes its only a notification for me, that i see the post request works ^^

Comment: SendJmeterFile.upload is a factory method, that will make a json request depends on the input fields

Comment: Once you called $interval in your code, it is started, so it has nothing common with your request, succesfull it is or not. Try to decrease interval timeout and debug it with Chrome DevTools and see, what is called first - request success callback or interval callback.
To make your interval function ran on request success callback, you should do the following: notification.poller = function (id) { return $interval(...) }